# Sending key input with Lua FFI?

Tags: c, lua, keypress, ffi, keystroke

I looked around on here and google for hours but could not find an example of what I'm looking for. If there is one I'm sorry in advance,

I'm decent at writing Lua but have no real understanding of C, I wanted to try the Lua FFI library which allows calling C functions and it seems to work well, I can do basic things like making a messagebox appear and whatnot (based on examples provided on ffi documentation).

One thing I'm really curious to do is see if I can create a simple botting script with something like SendInput for simulating keyboard events in game windows, but so far I'm having a lot of trouble figuring it out and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction, again, really sorry if this has been covered in another topic here or somewhere else.

Comment: Probably, this task is OS-dependent.  On Windows you can send any message to any particular window, including keystroke message (you should be able to specify id of the window, for example, by searching for its title).